# How to use nested non-static type as constructor parameter type?

Tags: typescript

In one of my classes I have a local non-static type and want to use that as the type of a constructor parameter. Using such a type requires a `this` reference (as it is non-static), but I get an error from Typescript saying that I cannot use `this` at this place. Here's the code:

```
export class CodePointBuffer extends JavaObject {
    public Type = (($outer) => {
        return class Type extends Enum<Type> {
            public static readonly BYTE: Type = new class extends Type {
            }(`BYTE`, 0);
            public static readonly CHAR: Type = new class extends Type {
            }(`CHAR`, 1);
            public static readonly INT: Type = new class extends Type {
            }(`INT`, 2);
        };
    })(this);

    private readonly type: InstanceType<typeof this.Type> | null;

    private constructor(type: InstanceType<typeof this.Type> | null) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

The member definition `CodePointBuffer.type` gives no error, but the `type` parameter in the constructor ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-teQZDIFcsu6EDoVSUqo+PtziauiY1RXcQA))

The error I get is:

> 'this' cannot be referenced in constructor arguments.
> (2333) 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class.(17009)

I can probably just suppress this error, as the type is erased anyway, but I would like to know if there's a better way to implement that.

Comment: Use bracket notation on CodePointBuffer then: https://tsplay.dev/NV7qGm

Comment: Yeah, the only reason to use `this` instead of `CodePointBuffer` is if you want subclasses to see narrower types, but since you've got `private` in there no subclasses will have access to those at all.

Comment: @vera. That approach works nicely. Care about writing an answer I can accept?

Comment: @jcalz Well, the only reason why is it done like this is because the original Java source I translated does it this way. I probably convert that to native TS yet, but I use these cases to learn more about Typescript.