# How to access a static member of an expression which represents an inner class in the outer class?

Tags: typescript

This is a follow up of this question: [How to use nested non-static type as constructor parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75276145/how-to-use-nested-non-static-type-as-constructor-parameter-type)

All required type definitions are now in place and the final puzzle piece is how to use the members of the inner class from code in the outer class. Here's an example:

```
class JavaObject {
}

class Enum<T> {
  public constructor(public name: string, public value: number) {}
}

export class CodePointBuffer extends JavaObject {
    public Type = (($outer) => {
        return class Type extends Enum<Type> {
            public static readonly BYTE: Type = new class extends Type {
            }(`BYTE`, 0);
            public static readonly CHAR: Type = new class extends Type {
            }(`CHAR`, 1);
            public static readonly INT: Type = new class extends Type {
            }(`INT`, 2);
        };
    })(this);

    private readonly type: InstanceType<typeof this.Type>;

    public constructor(type: CodePointBuffer.Type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static withBytes = (): CodePointBuffer => {
        return new CodePointBuffer(this.Type.BYTE);
    };
}

export namespace CodePointBuffer {
    export type Type = InstanceType<CodePointBuffer["Type"]>;
}
```

The initialisation of the `type` member of `CodePointBuffer` does not compile, because `CodePointBuffer.Type.BYTE` is not accepted. I also tried variations like `CodePointBuffer["Type"].BYTE` and `this.Type.BYTE`, to no avail.

What's the correct syntax in this case?

**Playground Link:** [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Ki58lgjzeXzSPAaLQQHhgZ3BMIdhM9lKy9d+b3Yy51e0bJ0u15Mced7tJ6QAbQARAsvwBdQMSEIIA)

Comment: Make `Type` be static? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-hRvS5iCQgA

Comment: Otherwise accessing `CodePointBuffer.Type.BYTE` doesn't make much sense. You could also change it to `this.type = this.Type.BYTE;` since `Type` is on the instance not the class

Comment: Yes, making it static or a native TS enum would be the better solution, but I want to know how to do it with the given situation (if possible at all). And I have already tried `this.Type.BYTE`, which is not accepted.

Comment: I mean this isn't really a TS issue. At runtime Type is on the instance not on the class, so accessing  it with `CodePointBuffer.Type.BYTE` doesn't really make sense. Why isn't `this.Type.BYTE` ok ?

Comment: Seems to work : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBSYDcwHkBGArApsALtA3gL4BQokMAogHYCuAtgDwAqAfAdAA42ogCWw0YAHsqEHACcauIeIAUXHv2hUwdTAC5oY8byoBzADSdufAUhA0Ny+qkziAlAULQSmAB4cZeMlGgBhIQATTAAFIV0cACEaADMYu2h3HEwqQJh4JDQsXAJiaHzjRQEmAE8OTGgAXmhZWQASIRpkhyq2fDyCzvFMHBpxKkFwX1LyxLdk1MpaRhHMNo7OxcLTLRwwHCVusECREBLoSIBNJgpNWarlTAB3QfIxibToc-alpcJZAAMjk4+jAAZ7ABuBavfIKFZidabTDbXb7PwACQAggAlM5lCrVKjXW6+JIpR7PEGg94fRGo37QACMQOJBUIwM6hHsshwAAteBBaSCODokMloFsdlQ9tAcBjNABJURrKjATCzBgBYJhCLROJ2ADaAHJZtqALosRkFcFKYQyyTSOSOF6vCA0crW41LdmcgB04tG1VdEDdszd3wozpcxBIQA

Comment: My fault, I removed a bit too much from my class for this question. The main problem lies in a static method. I added that to the question. But I see now why this cannot work. It tries to access a non-static member in a static context.